# cocos2d + iphone: What is the simplest method to work with vector images in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to import svg files in a `cocos2d` project.

Why are they so complicated to implement? I downloaded `monkVG` and all the other libraries but get `errors` for missing this or that.

What is the simplest method for working with vector images like svg in iOS?